# How to plot two series on a graph in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, plot, series

I want to plot the depth against a variable for 800 files.

I am trying to plot two series, the depth from say 1-10m and the rest of the data 10-1m.

```vb
    FileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    FileName = Left(FileName, (InStrRev(FileName, ".") - 1))
    Range("B1").Value = Mid(FileName, 5, 4) + Mid(FileName, 10, 2) + Mid(FileName, 13, 7) + "_SVP_MVP_LO"
    FileName = Range("B1").Value
        
    Range("B7").Select
    
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = ActiveSheet.Range("$C$15:$C$1000")
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = ActiveSheet.Range("$B$15:$B$1000")`
```

The data is in two columns but the bottom depth varies.

One idea is to plot until the cell value-previous cell value = +ve?

Would using the MAX function be a better idea, and plot to the MAX value then plotting the remainder?